# Listview item horizontal in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to list item horizontal in my app.
I see Printerest App in showcase xamarin, it has the same case.

I use [CarouselView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) but it show fullsceen.

Please, give me a solution.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try this http://www.fabiocozzolino.eu/a-little-and-simple-bindable-horizontal-scroll-view/

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own horizontal list using ScrollView and StackLayout.

Something like this:

```
public class HorizontalList : Grid
{
    private ICommand innerSelectedCommand;
    private ScrollView scrollview;
    private StackLayout mainPanel;
    public event EventHandler SelectedItemChanged;
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("SelectedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(HorizontalList), null);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(HorizontalList), default(IEnumerable<object>), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: ItemsSourceChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(HorizontalList), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(HorizontalList), default(DataTemplate));

    public ICommand SelectedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SelectedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var itemsLayout = (HorizontalList)bindable;
        itemsLayout.SetItems();
    }

    public HorizontalList()
    {
        scrollview = new ScrollView();
        mainPanel = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        scrollview.Content = mainPanel;
        scrollview.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal
        Children.Add(scrollview);
    }

    protected virtual void SetItems()
    {
        mainPanel.Children.Clear();

        if (ItemsSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        innerSelectedCommand = new Command<View>(view =>
        {
            SelectedItem = view.BindingContext;
            SelectedItem = null; // Allowing item second time selection
        });

        foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
        {
            mainPanel.Children.Add(GetItemView(item));
        }

        SelectedItem = null;
    }

    protected virtual View GetItemView(object item)
    {
        var content = ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
        var view = content as View;

        if (view == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        view.BindingContext = item;

        var gesture = new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = innerSelectedCommand,
            CommandParameter = view
        };

        AddGesture(view, gesture);

        return view;
    }

    private void AddGesture(View view, TapGestureRecognizer gesture)
    {
        view.GestureRecognizers.Add(gesture);

        var layout = view as Layout<View>;

        if (layout == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var child in layout.Children)
        {
            AddGesture(child, gesture);
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var itemsView = (HorizontalList)bindable;
        if (newValue == oldValue && newValue != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        itemsView.SelectedItemChanged?.Invoke(itemsView, EventArgs.Empty);

        if (itemsView.SelectedCommand?.CanExecute(newValue) ?? false)
        {
            itemsView.SelectedCommand?.Execute(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-netflix-sample/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Netflix/Xamarin.Netflix/Controls/HorizontalList/HorizontalList.cs) is the example of the similar approach.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17545919)

Comment: @khellang, thanks for pointing out. I have added the code for better understanding. But I think, I mentioned the approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView and set the Rotation to 270 degree.

[This](https://zepfiro.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/xamarin-forms-horizontal-listview/) is an example.

Please note that you may need to change the height and width for you requirement and

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650584/xamarin-forms-rotating-listview-adjust-row-width) might be useful for you.