# Custom RecyclerView for Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-recyclerview, horizontallistview

I'm having an issue when displaying a large number of visual elements in a scroll viewer, and I've tried every possible way to achieve the same approach, either with 3rd party horizontal list views (Can't find one with variable column/element width) or with rotated native list view (gives weird results).

The only approach that gives the result is via stacklayout docked in scrollviewer where I populate that stacklayout from code. Now the problem is all elements are rendered even if they were not displayed, so it makes the application either very slow.

I thought about having a recyclerview (which exists in native android) but I can't find an approach for it forms as it only exists in android. Now can anyone help me with that? Maybe a custom view where it uses recycler view on android and any similar approach or maybe a regular scrollviewer on iOS ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update #1**

I could do the rotated listview option using this code -Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41608874/9277972)-

```xml
<RelativeLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" Rotation="-90" HasUnevenRows="True"
              RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=-37}"
              RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=-0.5, Constant=37}"
              RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}"
              RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <BoxView Rotation="90" BackgroundColor="Beige" WidthRequest="200"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I can never make this box view fill the while cell, there is always empty space -The box view is a place holder instead of other custom control-.

Is there a method to make the box view always fill the whole cell height and fill and expand it to it's **WidthRequest** property -Which will be dynamic according to a binding later- ?

Comment: Have you tried [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) ?

Comment: Form's `CollectionView` uses `RecyclerView` on Android, if a CollectionView does not meet your Forms UI requirements, you can review the source to implement your own control : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/search?q=recyclerview&type=

Comment: The CollectionView doesn't offer a direct content like the scroll viewer, and also if used as list doesn't offer a horizontal one with dynamic item width...

Comment: Not sure if I understand the 1st part of your reply. For the second part, you can create a custom Android `ViewHolder` for the `RecyclerView` your dynamic item's width (this is how I would do it on Android native). This is how the various variants of CollectionView are done in Forms: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/search?q=recyclerview+viewholder

Comment: The first part I meant to use the collection view as a scroll view, nesting it with a very wide stacklayout and it renders only the visible objects in this stacklayout. Also, I'm looking for a solution for both Android and iOS, so I can't really do something for only one...

Comment: Maybe you should look for third-party libraries that are compatible with both Android and ios platforms.

Comment: I tried and looked for it with no luck... I'm trying now to redesign my element to be rotated to get over the issue -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for such an issue by using a listview with custom template, where I inside of it I used several scrollviews and linked their movement together. Refer to my answer here: [How to make multiple list views scroll together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64420241/how-to-make-multiple-list-views-scroll-together)