# How to make multiple list views scroll together?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scroll

I'm having a vertical list view which has in its item template another list view in horizontal position, now everything works fine, but I want to be able to scroll all of these sub list views if one of them scrolled.

Here is an illustration:
[image: Illustration]

Now I want all the sub list views in all rows to scroll together.
How can I do this?!

Maybe I can make an extending class for the list view with bindable property for scrolling ?!
Something like this:

```cs
public class ScrollableListView : ListView {
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScrollProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ScrollPosition", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollableListView));
    public double ScrollPosition
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ScrollProperty, value);
            ScrollToAsync(0, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in xaml bind all `ScrollPosition` property to a variable that changes whenever a list is scrolled, like this:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <RelativeLayout HeightRequest="{Binding Width}" Margin="{Binding Margin}">
        <Grid Rotation="90" AnchorX="0" AnchorY="0"
              RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
              RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"
              RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}">

            <Local:ScrollableListView ScrollPosition="{Binding SPos}" Scrolled="Generic_Scroll_Event"/>
        </Grid>
    </RelativeLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

And in the `Generic_Scroll_Event` The `SPos` variable changes to the event sender's position.

This is just something that popped in my head ... Any help is appreciated anyway ^^.

Comment: Can you provide one sample that you have tried here? I will try to reproduce your problem and try to give one solution.

Comment: Well, I tried, but `ScrollTo` functions doesn't take position -_- instead, an item to scroll to...

Comment: Please provide one simple sample at github, I will download your sample to test, and try to give one solution.

Comment: There is no sample... I have nothing to test... I'm not looking for a fix, I'm looking for an idea or some workaround to achiever the job, which is making multiple listviews scroll together.

Comment: If you don't provide simple sample, I can not reproduce your problem at my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer should work, but as there is no direct way of making a listview scroll to a position I had to make a workaround.

I used scrollviews instead and used it's template to work as a listview, then binded all of the scrollviews to the first one, in two way mode.